# NEST Elasticsearch error : The underlying connection was closed

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm having an issue connecting through an ElasticSearch cluster using NEST client.

On my development machine I can connect and run queries against elastic (running on my local machine) just fine, but on our staging environment I get the error "System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.".

Our staging environment consists of 4 Linux machines running Elastic, and a Windows machine running our client software.

I already set the DisableDirectStreaming() on the connectionsettings. I also tried setting `<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />` in my web.config, but the error still exists (but now the ApiCall.OriginalException is NULL).

Sending the query via Kopf interface, returns result, so the cluster seems to be operational.

Anybody have a clue what is going wrong here?

**Update:**
The query I'm running is (where indexFilter en searchFilter are filled based on user request):
This query does work on my local ES (Windows / ES 2.1.1), but not on my production ES (Ubuntu / ES 2.1.1)

```
QueryContainer indexFilter = new QueryContainer();
QueryContainer searchFilter = new QueryContainer();

var result = db.Client.Search<IndexRecord>
(
    search => search
    .Query
    (
        f => f.HasChild<SearchRecord>
        (
            c => c
            .Query
            (
                f2 => searchFilter
            )
        ) & indexFilter
    )
    .Sort
    (
        ss => ss.Ascending(f => f.AccommodationName)
    )
    .Size(10)
);
```

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of request that it happens on? Is it intermittent? Generally, you don't want to set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` unless you want to buffer the request/response bytes for some purpose e.g. logging all requests

Comment: I'm running ES 2.1.1. on Ubuntu 15.10. The `.DisableDirectStreaming()` was set because of a suggestion it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. Somehow the client was talking to port 9300 in stead of port 9200. I fixed this issue and now getting results back from ES.